# Twilio - SMS (UK) - Possible to have Name and not number come through?

Tags: twilio, sms

I'm new to forum but just wanted to know if anyone knew if it was possible to get a Twilio SMS number (UK mobile) to come from a name as opposed to a number? An example would be that I see SMSs come to me with a business name on them.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you are looking for here is an [alphanumeric sender ID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-alphanumeric-sender-id). Twilio supports alphanumeric sender IDs for sending SMS in [all the countries listed here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) and that includes the UK. Note that you will need to use an upgraded account to send messages from an alphanumeric sender ID.

There are [more details on alphanumeric sender IDs and Twilio here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS).

Comment: Thanks Phil. Very usefully. Many apologies for the delay in seeing and responding to this.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please do mark the answer as correct if it helped too. Thanks!